# Section syntax with old MASM3 do not reachable data section

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, masm

I am new in assembler.

I can not compile and link in masm3 this code. When I enter a data section than masm found the data area not. Then i have a bug in this code. All msg text will be write into the test1.txt file. > 16bit DOS / COM

Strange is, that in MASM3 the data section is not reachable but in MASM611 it work.
The next why will be write all data (when I use 611) all msg texts into the file. The goal is write me only.

[after use "masm test.asm"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4J80.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4J80.png) > https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4J80.png

```
.8086
.model tiny

data:
filename  db "test1.txt", 0
handle   dw 0
usermsg   db "write me$", 0
;buffer times 200 db  0
msg_open  db "Error opening file!$"
msg_seek  db "Error seeking file!$"
msg_write db "Error writing file!$"
msg_close db "Error closing file!$"
END data

.stack 100h

.code
 org 100h


start:

   mov ah, 3dh
   mov al, 2
   mov dx, offset filename
   int 21h
   jc err_open

   mov [handle], ax

   mov bx, ax
   mov ah, 42h  ; "lseek"
   mov al, 2    ; position relative to end of file
   mov cx, 0    ; offset MSW
   mov dx, 0    ; offset LSW
   int 21h
   jc err_seek

   mov bx, [handle]
   mov dx, offset usermsg   < Here I offset usermsg only
   mov cx, 100
   mov ah, 40h
   int 21h ; write to file...  > Here will be write all msg, usermsg is in dx only.
   jc err_write

   mov bx, [handle]
   mov ah, 3eh
   int 21h ; close file...
   jc err_close

exit:
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h

err_open:
   mov dx, offset msg_open
   jmp error

err_seek:   
   mov dx, offset msg_seek
   jmp error

err_write:
   mov dx, offset msg_write
   jmp error

err_close:
   mov dx, offset msg_close
   ; fallthrough

error:
   mov ah, 09h
   int 21h

   mov ax, 4c01h
   int 21h

end start

END
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4J80.png):

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at a Masm 3.0 manual online, and I don't see `.model` or `.data` or `.code` directives. For a tiny (.COM) program, the first instruction can be a jump to the start to skip around the data, or have the data after the code. Instead of `.data` or `.code`, `segment` directives can be used instead. However, for a .com (tiny) program, only a single segment is used. DS and CS are initialized to the program prefix (like command line info), below the org 100h code, so the code starts at CS:0100h.

```
_DATA   segment para public 'DATA'
_DATA   ends
DGROUP  group   _DATA
_BSS    segment para public 'BSS'
_BSS    ends
DGROUP  group   _BSS
STACK   segment para STACK 'STACK'
        db      512 dup (?)
STACK   ends
DGROUP  group   STACK
_TEXT   segment word public 'CODE'
        assume  cs:_TEXT,ds:DGROUP
start:   ...
_TEXT   ends
        end     start
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Where can i find the Masm 3.0 manual online?

Comment: @Born34 - do a web search for masm 3.0 manual. One of the links I found was [this one](https://www.pcjs.org/documents/manuals/microsoft): scroll down to find image files of the reference and user guides.

Comment: Thank you very much. I downloaded everything for the future world ;)
I found this site before but I do not see it